# spring boot application does not exit after all tasks are completed

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

This is my Application class -

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

@Autowired
private ITestService3 testService3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)));

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        testService3.multiThreadTest();
    }
}
```

Method -

```
public void multiThreadTest() {
    ThreadPoolExecutor readExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<String> files = listFiles(new File("/Users/admin/filesList"), new ArrayList<>());
    for (String file : files) {
        readExecutor.execute(new FileParser(file));
    }
}
```

Even after all the files are read, the application is not terminated
However when i use

> System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)));

Application is terminated and all the threads are killed.

And when i use -

> SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).close();

Threads continue to run even after the application says this -

> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6eda5c9: startup date [Mon Aug 15 04:42:02 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   2016-08-15 04:42:05.390  INFO 36600 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

And then i have to manually kill the application. And the application exits with code 130

Can someone please help me with a way to gracefully shutdown the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you are not closing the `ExecutorService` properly, your `multiThreadTest` should look like:

```
public void multiThreadTest() throws InterruptedException {
    ThreadPoolExecutor readExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<String> files = listFiles(new File("/Users/admin/filesList"), new ArrayList<>());
    for (String file : files) {
        readExecutor.execute(new FileParser(file));
    }

    readExecutor.shutdown();
    readExecutor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // wait for tasks to complete
    readExecutor.shutdownNow();
}
```

Comment: My application runs for a very long duration. May be days too. In that case how to set this - readExecutor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

Comment: You can use `DAYS` time unit - `readExecutor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.DAYS)`

Comment: You don't really need the last two lines - `awaitTermination` and `shutdownNow` but it is a good practice to have a threshold on how long a task can run.